# opentok angular turn off camera when in different route

Tags: angularjs, opentok

Im building an angular app with opentok. I noticed that when I navigate to a different state, (by the way im using ui-router fo my routing) the camera is still being used. How do I turn it off?

Comment: Was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your state code to look something like below:

```
$stateProvider.state("camera-on", {
  template: ...,
  controller: ...,
  onExit: function(){
        //Todo: Code to turn off camera here.
  }
})
```

For **onExit** reference documentation, check [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks) out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the opentok-angular library? If you destroy the scope it will clean up the camera. https://github.com/aullman/OpenTok-Angular/blob/master/opentok-angular.js#L143

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy